# Send json as data attribute with jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress, backbone.js

### Update:

I was trying to post a model with a nested collection by jquery ajax.
However the backbone method .toJSON() can't handle nested collections.

I found a pretty nice way to modify .toJSON() and make it recursive here:

http://www.shesek.info/web-development/recursive-backbone-models-tojson

### Original question:

I'm working on a Wordpress pluging, using Backbone.js, and I've got a model that I need to send serverside, later to be forwarded to an external server via curl.

Problem is: I really can't find a way to post the model from backbone.js to the wordpress server (the same server as the backbone javascript file).

I've tried to override model.save method like this:

```
App.Models.Order = Backbone.Model.extend({
   save: function() {
   var model = this;
   jQuery.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      url: my_plugin_ajax_namespace.ajaxurl,
         data: {
         action: 'my_plugin_order_function',
         my_plugin_namespace_order: JSON.stringify(model.toJSON())
      },
      success: function(response) {
     console.log('order saved');
         console.log(response);
      }
   }
});
```

The my_plugin_order_function trying to receive and decode the json model looks like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_plugin_order_function', 'my_plugin_order_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_plugin_order_function', 'my_plugin_order_function');

function my_plugin_order_function() {
   $order = json_decode($_POST['my_plugin_namespace_order']);
   /* supposed to do some curl stuff here, but when testing, just return the same model */
   $result = $order;
   echo json_encode($result);
   die();
}
```

However I just get null!

Been googling a lot, but can't find an answer to this. I can't set content-type to json, since action is not a json, right? Should I really use stringify.JSON like this? Is it a bad solution to override the model.save method?
I am actually trying to just send one of the data properties as a json. Is this even possible?

Comment: What error do you get on the regular save function? Overriding doesn't seem right here. But if you want to override see this: http://jstarrdewar.com/blog/2012/07/20/the-correct-way-to-override-concrete-backbone-methods/

Comment: I haven't even tried the regular save method, since it just posts the model as json to a defined url. I need to post the model as json AND ALSO an action for wordpress to catch the ajax request.

Comment: I'd do it in a coupled way. I'd say something like model.save().done(send_ajax_request())

Comment: Hmm, I tried to reproduce the error in a minimalistic way by just posting an ajax request with data: { action: 'some action', json_model: {  title: 'Tada!', message: 'it works?' }} to a simple php page. And it actually works (with and without JSON.stringify). Really strange....

Comment: Can you post an update with the code that calls the save function? Backbone applies some more logic than you might think.

Comment: I've found the problem! The model I am trying to post is actually nested: a model with an attribute that is a collection of other models. Seems like the toJSON() method is not able to convert this to a json.